# Spring Boot app fails to start when all beans are marked as Lazy, as it can't find an error channel

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

In Spring Boot 2.2, you can mark all beans as being lazy by default.

If I turn this on via

`spring.main.lazy-initialization=true`

I get the following message:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

A component required a bean named 'errorChannel' that could not be found.
```

The code in question that references this is:

```
@MessagingGateway(errorChannel = "errorChannel")
@FunctionalInterface
public interface SomeInterface {
```

It looks like the lazy setting has stopped Spring Integration from creating the errorChannel.

How can I mark the errorChannel bean as being not lazy here ?

Also how can I exclude other classes from not being Lazy by default in Spring Boot 2.2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I get some lazy-related exception in other place though.
I guess your application is much complicated than you say in the question.

Anyway there is a `LazyInitializationExcludeFilter`:

```
@Bean
public static LazyInitializationExcludeFilter integrationExcludeFilter() {
    return (beanName, beanDefinition, beanType) -> "testChannel".equals(beanName);
}
```

See its JavaDocs:

```
/**
 * Filter that can be used to exclude beans definitions from having their
 * {@link AbstractBeanDefinition#setLazyInit(boolean) lazy-init} set by the
 * {@link LazyInitializationBeanFactoryPostProcessor}.
 * <p>
 * Primarily intended to allow downstream projects to deal with edge-cases in which it is
 * not easy to support lazy-loading (such as in DSLs that dynamically create additional
 * beans). Adding an instance of this filter to the application context can be used for
 * these edge cases.
 * <p>
 * A typical example would be something like this:
 * <p>
 * <pre><code>
 * &#64;Bean
 * public static LazyInitializationExcludeFilter integrationLazyInitializationExcludeFilter() {
 *   return LazyInitializationExcludeFilter.forBeanTypes(IntegrationFlow.class);
 * }</code></pre>
 * <p>
 * NOTE: Beans of this type will be instantiated very early in the spring application
 * lifecycle so they should generally be declared static and not have any dependencies.
 *
 * @author Tyler Van Gorder
 * @author Philip Webb
 * @since 2.2.0
 */
@FunctionalInterface
public interface LazyInitializationExcludeFilter {
```

I don't know yet how to fix it from the framework perspective...

Comment: Thanks, this should do it.  Much appreciated.