# Spring Integration beans aren't created when spring.main.lazy-initialization=true

Tags: spring, spring-integration

With reference to my earlier question here

[Spring Boot app fails to start when all beans are marked as Lazy, as it can't find an error channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58763720/spring-boot-app-fails-to-start-when-all-beans-are-marked-as-lazy-as-it-cant-fi)

and a reference to the issue here:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/16184#issuecomment-480196051

does anyone know what beans need to be added to an instance of `LazyInitializationExcludeFilter` in order for Spring Integration to start when `spring.main.lazy-initialization=true` ?

I'm getting errors like below, saying that "myErrorChannel" bean isn't available, where this is defined in code like so:

```
@MessagingGateway(errorChannel = "myErrorChannel")
@FunctionalInterface
public interface SomeInterface{
}
```

How can I make the creation of the error channel eager rather than lazy ? Adding a LazyInitializationExcludeFilter and trying to filter out beans called "myErrorChannel" doesn't work, as there must be another (lazy) bean that isn't creating the errorChannel bean.

Stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'myErrorChannel' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:805)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1278)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:297)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207)
    at org.springframework.integration.support.channel.BeanFactoryChannelResolver.resolveDestination(BeanFactoryChannelResolver.java:89)
    at org.springframework.integration.support.channel.BeanFactoryChannelResolver.resolveDestination(BeanFactoryChannelResolver.java:46)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.getErrorChannel(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:414)
    at org.springframework.integration.graph.IntegrationGraphServer$NodeFactory.gatewayNode(IntegrationGraphServer.java:374)
    at org.springframework.integration.graph.IntegrationGraphServer.lambda$gateways$5(IntegrationGraphServer.java:258)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap$UnmodifiableEntrySet.lambda$entryConsumer$0(Collections.java:1577)
    at java.util.HashMap$EntrySpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1699)
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap$UnmodifiableEntrySet$UnmodifiableEntrySetSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1602)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:485)
    at org.springframework.integration.graph.IntegrationGraphServer.gateways(IntegrationGraphServer.java:263)
    at org.springframework.integration.graph.IntegrationGraphServer.buildGraph(IntegrationGraphServer.java:184)
    at org.springframework.integration.graph.IntegrationGraphServer.onApplicationEvent(IntegrationGraphServer.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.graph.IntegrationGraphServer.onApplicationEvent(IntegrationGraphServer.java:66)
```

Comment: Why an explicit `@Bean` definition for that `myErrorChannel` doesn't help?

Answer (score 1):

Solved by making any beans that are created in this manner as lazy:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow someBeanName() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("someString")
            .handle(restCallFailedHandler())
            .handle(finishedHandler())
            .get();
}
```